# Find coefficient that makes constraint non-binding

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, inverse-problems

I have a problem in the following setting:

- We maximize a concave quadratic objective function over a polytope, so we have a QP. All the variables are non-negative and are required to sum up to one.
- If we optimize this problem, we know that the optimal solution $x^*$ fulfills $x^*_i < a$ for some special index $i$ and some given positive value $a \in (0,1)$.
- Now we add the constraint $x_i \geq a$ to the problem. This cuts off the previous optimal solution and the objective function value decreases.

The question is: By which amount $\Delta$ do we have to increase the coefficient of $x_i$ in the linear part of the objective function (without touching the quadratic part) such that an optimal solution to the problem *without* the additional constraint fulfills $x_i \geq a$ ? Like how valuable must $x_i$ become such that the constraint is no longer necessary.

Of course, for some sufficiently large value of the coefficient, the variable will dominate everything and we would assign $x_i = 1$. I also think that $x_i$ is monotonous in $\Delta$, so we could search for the correct value of $\Delta$ using binary search. However, I'm more interested in a direct method that is, e.g., based on another optimization problem.

This somehow reminds me of both sensitivity analysis and inverse optimization, but I didn't see such a problem in literature before.

Comment: Do you mean variables *nonnegative* in first bullet? (they sum to one...)

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: If you solve the dual of the constrained problem, then the amount $\Delta$ that you need to change the coefficient of $x_i$ by will be exactly equal to the optimal value of the dual variable corresponding to constraint.

Comment: Do you mean the Lagrangian dual? Is there any reference for this fact?

Comment: @p.s.: Sorry if I push this. Do you say that the optimal value of the dual variable is exactly equal to the amount $\Delta$ I am looking for? Or is it just a local approximation? Do you have a reference at hand where I can read more about this? I looked at Boyd/Vandenberghe but this problem is at least not directly tackled by them.

Comment: Dont have time for a full answer, but here are some hints: When you form the lagrangian you add a term of the form $\lambda(x_i-a)$. That $\lambda$ changes the linear coefficient of $x_i$. Because it's a qp, you have strong duality. The primal-dual optimal variables will satisfy kkt conditions, including complementary slackness.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. If you find the time, I'd still be very interested in a full answer. I only have a vague idea of how this argument should work.

Comment: @p.s. I'd still be very interested if you find the time :-)